# How to use 'Mysql JOIN' with sql text of same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I want to use mysql's "JOIN"

I want to group rows by "date_text" where "tokenIdx" is "1001" and "datetime_unix" is the highest value.

Is my code wrong?

```
 SELECT `A.idx` 
FROM `data_candle_h1` 'A'
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT `date_text`, MAX(`datetime_unix`) AS 'datetime_unix' 
        FROM `data_candle_h1` 
        WHERE `tokenIdx` = '1002' 
        GROUP BY `date_text`
    ) 'B'
ON `A.datetime_unix` = `B.datetime_unix` 
WHERE  `A.tokenIdx` = '1002'
```

[image: database table]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  A `JOIN` may not be necessary.

Comment: If your query produces a syntax error, then, yes; it's safe to say that it's wrong.

Comment: However, `SELECT A.idx FROM data_candle_h1 A JOIN (SELECT date_text, MAX(datetime_unix) datetime_unix FROM data_candle_h1 WHERE tokenIdx = 1002 GROUP BY date_text) B ON A.datetime_unix = B.datetime_unix WHERE A.tokenIdx = 1002` is a valid (and common) query. Whether it  does what you want, we couldn't say at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is syntactically perfect. Just remove single quotes('') around table aliases (A and B). I have corrected it. Please check this out.

```
SELECT `A.idx` 
FROM `data_candle_h1` A
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT `date_text`, MAX(`datetime_unix`) AS 'datetime_unix' 
        FROM `data_candle_h1` 
        WHERE `tokenIdx` = '1002' 
        GROUP BY `date_text`
    ) B
ON `A.datetime_unix` = `B.datetime_unix` 
WHERE  `A.tokenIdx` = '1002'
```

Comment: It was solved after removing the (``) surrounding column (ex. `A.tokenIdx`). 

Your advice that there is no problem with the syntax was helpful.
Thank you.